# How much time passes in the John Wick movies?

Tags: john-wick, john-wick-chapter-4

After watching John Wick Chapter 4, chatting about it with my girlfriend we talked about how John Wick looked so worn out by the end, and she said something like "well, yeah, he's been fighting non-stop for what? 3 days?"

And it got me thinking. We do know that Chapter 2 starts almost immediatelly after Chapter 1, and the same case with Chapter 3 which picks up immediatelly after the second one's cliffhanger. The thing I've been unable to find is how much time passed between the ending of 3 and the beginning of 4? Wick looks recovered from his fall at the end of Chapter 3 which I would guess takes a few weeks?

There is, of course, the travel, and how he manages to travel around the world with a bounty on his head, but maybe that's for a whole different question. Wick travels from New York to the middle east, to Paris, to Osaka, back to New York, back to Paris, so I guess that will take way more than a few days.

So...do we know how much time actually passes in all 4 movies? Is it days? A couple of weeks?

Comment: I think this is a trick question.  The events between 1 and 3 seem to be successive, and the screenwriter states it's a matter of 3 weeks.  However, the pit bull Wick takes at the end of 1 appears to be a puppy, or possibly 1 year old, while the "same" pit bull is clearly older at the beginning of Wick 3.  That's not a 3 week difference, closer to 2 year difference in the muscular structure of the dog.

Comment: @JohnnyBones are we sure it's the same dog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [interview with Chad Stahelski](https://collider.com/john-wick-timeline-director-chad-stahelski-comments/) just about that. His estimate for total time from beginning of the first to the end of the fourth John Wick film is... *less than a year*. With more precise, but still ballpark, figure being *seven to eight* months.

> So within a year, I think it all happens. I would say almost within 7 to 8 months.

Why so long? Because there's big timeskip after third film, about 6 months according to Stahelski. It's so long because Wick had to seriously re-convalesce after the events of the film.

On the other hand there's little in the way of timeskips during three first films. Indeed, Stahelski estimates it took less than two weeks from beginning of the first to the end of the third film.

> Well, we figured the first three movies almost happened in like a week, week and a half, somewhere in there.

Still, this isn't really *canonical* info, more of ballpark figurers. Personally I'd think the three films take a bit longer, because of his stab wound - it had to heal at least a bit, so he wouldn't pull his stitches sooner. Also journeys would take some time... but it could be less than two weeks.

Comment: This is a great find!! Thank you. As for canononical, it might count as "word of God" and could be valid. +1 and might accept if no other info comes up.

Answer (score 1):

The timeline of the John Wick movies is somewhat unclear, as the events of each film occur in relatively quick succession and there are no specific indicators of time passing. However, it is generally believed that each movie takes place over the course of a few days or possibly a week.

In the first John Wick movie, it is established that John has been retired from his life as an assassin for five years. The events of the movie are set in motion when his wife dies and he is targeted by his former employers, and the bulk of the story takes place over the course of a few intense days.

The second movie picks up shortly after the events of the first and follows John as he is once again pulled back into the world of assassins. Again, the timeline is not explicit, but it is believed that the events of the movie take place over the course of several days.

The third movie, John Wick: Chapter 3 – Parabellum, continues immediately after the events of the second and takes place over the course of a few days, as John fights to survive against a growing number of enemies.

Overall, it is safe to say that the events of the John Wick movies take place over a relatively short period of time, likely no more than a week.

The timeframe is extended by a few days with John Wick 4.

Comment: Any exact numbers? It feels that the 4 movies happen in the span of a week, or a couple of weeks, but it's hard to say with all the traveling. Since we saw the first 3 movies before going to the teather for the 4th, she says it felt like it all happened in 3, 4 days tops.

Comment: I think there are pretty big breaks between Wick making peace with Russians in the beginning of 2 and mafioso coming, and during his visits to Bowery when he reconvalesces. I wouldn't be very surprised if all four films covered even half a year.